# Error in calling Rest Services from Angular JS in a Spring Boot application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, spring-boot, jakarta-ee

Spring Boot application hosting REST services at back-end and Angular at front-end.
I am calling the REST from UI.

> My Code

```
$http.get(urls.USER_SERVICE_API)
                .then(
                    function (response) {
                        console.log('Fetched successfully all users');
                        $localStorage.users = response.data;
                        deferred.resolve(response);
                    },
                    function (errResponse) {
                        console.error('Error while loading users');
                        deferred.reject(errResponse);
                    }
                );


app.constant('urls', {
BASE: '<a class="vglnk" href="http://localhost:8081/SpringBootCRUDApp" rel="nofollow"><span>http</span><span>://</span><span>localhost</span><span>:</span><span>8081</span><span>/</span><span>SpringBootCRUDApp</span></a>',
USER_SERVICE_API : '<a class="vglnk" href="http://localhost:8081/SpringBootCRUDApp/api/user/" rel="nofollow"><span>http</span><span>://</span><span>localhost</span><span>:</span><span>8081</span><span>/</span><span>SpringBootCRUDApp</span><span>/</span><span>api</span><span>/</span><span>user</span><span>/</span></a>'
});
```

The error debug in Google chrome browser shows below :

```
angular.min.js:103 GET http://localhost:8081/SpringBootCRUDApp/%3Ca%20class=%22vglnk%22%20href=%22http://localhost:8080/SpringBootCRUDApp/api/user/%22%20rel=%22nofollow%22%3E%3Cspan%3Ehttp%3C/span%3E%3Cspan%3E://%3C/span%3E%3Cspan%3Elocalhost%3C/span%3E%3Cspan%3E:%3C/span%3E%3Cspan%3E8080%3C/span%3E%3Cspan%3E/%3C/span%3E%3Cspan%3ESpringBootCRUDApp%3C/span%3E%3Cspan%3E/%3C/span%3E%3Cspan%3Eapi%3C/span%3E%3Cspan%3E/%3C/span%3E%3Cspan%3Euser%3C/span%3E%3Cspan%3E/%3C/span%3E%3C/a%3E 404
```

[image]

When calling the REST from POSTMAN, it is successful. Hence there is a problem while calling from the UI. Please help me to find out what I am doing wrong in the UI rest calling part.

```
Complete REST URL is ::

http://localhost:8081/SpringBootCRUDApp/api/user/
```

Please help !

Comment: Dude... USER_SERVICE_API is `'<a class="vglnk" href="http://localhost:8081/SpringBootCRUDApp/api/user/" rel="nofollow"><span>http</span><span>://</span><span>localhost</span><span>:</span><span>8081</span><span>/</span><span>SpringBootCRUDApp</span><span>/</span><span>api</span><span>/</span><span>user</span><span>/</span></a>`, not `http://localhost:8081/SpringBootCRUDApp/api/user/` as you expect....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong URL in your app.constants. Replacing that with the REST URL should give you the desired result.

`USER_SERVICE_API: 'http://localhost:8081/SpringBootCRUDApp/api/user'`

The URL currently specified by you has a lot of unknown tags in it.

Comment: Yes. I have rectified the URL and removed all unnecessary tags . its working now. Thank You.

app.constant('urls', {
    BASE: 'http://localhost:8081/SpringBootCRUDApp',
    USER_SERVICE_API : 'http://localhost:8081/SpringBootCRUDApp/api/user/'
});